# Insert text block to file after multi line section

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to insert this multi line text block to a file:

```
:msg, contains, "ignore" stop
mail.*                           -/var/log/maillog
```

The block needs to be added immediately after this block of text in the file:

```
#
# Logging for the mail system.  Split it up so that
# it is easy to write scripts to parse these files.
#
```

I am trying to do this by using the `blockinfile` module:

```
- name: Add custom maillog config
  blockinfile:
    path: /etc/rsyslog.conf
    backup: yes
    insertafter: "#\n# Logging for the mail system.  Split it up so that\n# it is easy to write scripts to parse these files.\n#"
    block: |-
      :msg, contains, "ignore" stop
      mail.*                           -/var/log/maillog
    state: present
```

But the `insertafter` is ignored and the block gets added to the end of the file. The regex should be matching the block but I think `insertafter` does not support multi line inputs. I can't use the last line of the block since there are other lines in the file that matches `#`. How can this be done?

Comment: [`blockinfile:`'s `insertafter` attribute](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/5/collections/ansible/builtin/blockinfile_module.html#parameter-insertafter) is a regex, not a multi-line literal, so I think the best you can do is match the `^# it is easy ...` part since `^#` will match all over your file. While this isn't what you asked, you may also be a lot happier [with `rsyslog.d` style](https://rsyslog.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/global/options/rsconf1_includeconfig.html) instead of Editing The One Magic File

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use module replace: (you add (?m) to specify multiline, but no functional with blockinfile)

sample of file.txt

```
firstline
#
# Logging for the mail system.  Split it up so that
# it is easy to write scripts to parse these files.
#
oneline
another line
```

the playbook:

```
- name: "tips1"
  hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - replace:
        path: file.txt
        regexp: '(?m){{after}}'
        replace: '{{after}}{{rep}}\n'
      vars: 
        after: |
          #
          # Logging for the mail system.  Split it up so that
          # it is easy to write scripts to parse these files.
          #
        rep: |
          :msg, contains, "ignore" stop
          mail.*                           -/var/log/maillog
```

result file.txt:

```
firstline
#
# Logging for the mail system.  Split it up so that
# it is easy to write scripts to parse these files.
#
:msg, contains, "ignore" stop
mail.*                           -/var/log/maillog  
oneline
another line
```

so to keep the task idempotent, i suggest you to use this regex:

```
  tasks:
    - replace:
        path: file.txt
        regexp: '(?m){{after}}{{rep}}\n|{{after}}'
        replace: '{{after}}{{rep}}\n'
      vars:
        after: |
          #
          # Logging for the mail system.  Split it up so that
          # it is easy to write scripts to parse these files.
          #
        rep: |
          :msg, contains, "ignore" stop
          mail.*                           -/var/log/maillog
```